# How to validate many fields combined in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Is there a creative and easy way to check many form fields at once.

I have a form with generated fields on the fly, each has a unique id.

The thing is submitting all the fields are not required, but at least one field must be filled before submitting.

Is there a way to do this in Codeigniter, or how would I go about validating this effectively.

I understand that it is possible to check each field individually, but I'm seeking for a much cleaner way.

I hope it's clear for you guys. Thanks.

Comment: How are your input fields named?

Comment: a `prefix` followed by a `timestamp` for a date in a range of dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, I have a custom function which will batch check every submission on my form to make sure it meets a set of rules. I am thinking that it may work to set up my form as an html array (`data[]`), retrieve it in code igniter, then use the CI `callback_` validation function to make sure everything turns out okay. It seems complex, so I haven't yet entirely wrapped my head around it, but maybe this can get your wheels turning in the right direction.

**EDIT:**

```
$this->load->library('form_validation');

// If there is any posted data, then we should assign it to our $post_data array.

$post_data = $this->input->post('project_data');
if (empty($post_data)) {die('empty form');}

// Now, we are ready to validate the incoming data.
// We will send the data through a callback function which will check to make sure it is valid.
// If it is not valid, the callback function will trigger a codeigniter validation error.

// Let's temporarily remove any commas from the submission data to avoid delimiter confusion when sending it through the callback

$post_data = str_replace(",", "DELIMITEDCOMMA", $post_data);

$post_data_str = http_build_query($post_data);
$this->form_validation->set_rules("project_data[errors]", 'Errors', "required|callback__validate_project_data[$post_data_str]");

$this->form_validation->run();
```

Then, just write your custom validation function based on what it is that you need to validate.

```
function _validate_project_data($value, $request)
{
    // A callback rule check is being attempted by the CI validator 
    // $value is the actual value of the submission, while $request is the key and value

    $request = explode(",", $request);
    $request = str_replace("DELIMITEDCOMMA", ",", $request);

    // rename the keys in the request back to the original convention

    parse_str($request[0], $request); 
    //var_dump($request);

    // perform validation here and return true or false (valid or invalid)      

}
```

Comment: I was away for a while, I couldn't understand what you mean. For the time being i'm looping through all the fields and returning a single error even if one fails. Not very convenient. But I'll try to understand what you meant and try to implement.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
$_POST['data_you_want_to_validate_together'] = $_POST['first_field'] . $_POST['second_field'];
$this->form_validation->set_rules('data_you_want_to_validate_together','Some Data', 'required|callback_some_function');
```

Now you can get the data via:

```
echo $this->input->post('data_you_want_to_validate_together');
```

Answer (score -2):

Not entirely sure what you mean, as the fields would have to be checked individually whichever way you do it. Unless you're concatenating all the inputs and checking that? Maybe I've missed something there though.

Just go for client side: http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/validator/index.html

Serverside: http://formigniter.org/

Hope this helps...